# WooCommerce Store Notice does not update with new text

Tags: woocommerce

I've inherited a WooCommerce Storefront and need to post a message with the Store Notice feature.

I have updated the text, enable it and publish.

I expect the new text to appear on the banner - in my case on top of the page - but right away the text reverts to an old message. When I go back to the settings page, that old text is in the text area so obviously it overwrote my newly inserted message.

I searched for the string in all the code and it's not hardcoded but I can't find from where it's fetching it.

The only way of making it change is by deleting all the text box and then a 'default' demo text appears in the store notice.

Any clue where is that text stored and why I can't update it with a new message?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

1) Are you sure you are not seeing a cache? That seems most likely. Try deactivating all caching plugins (WP Rocket, W3 Total Cache, Swift Performance etc), clearing all cache and viewing the website in Incognito mode / new browser.

2) This may be stored as a setting in the wp_options table. You could check that for the new/old string

3) Are you logged in as Admin? Perhaps you don't have permission to change that string?

Comment: Thanks. I cleared up all the existing caches, tried incognito and same thing.. the issue is that the old value comes back into the backend, it's not a frontend problem. I update it and after publishing it comes back.
I'm Admin, I checked that too... I will check now the wp_options and see. Thanks!